# Show sum of values for all checkboxes that are checked

Tags: javascript, forms, checkbox

I’m creating an HTML form and want to achieve the following with JS, please provide the code i should use to do so.

1.Add values of all the checked checkboxes and show them as total.

2.Add a restriction the user must select at least 2 checkboxes.
Here is my code.

```
<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E33" value="4500" />
<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E34" value="3000" />
<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E36" value="6000" />

<p>Your Total is = </p>
```

Also code should be such that if i add or remove checkboxes i should not have to modify the JS code too.

Comment: I think you missed something when reading [ask]. SO is not a code writing service, we help with written code, so make an effort of your own and come back if that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all the checkbox using `document.getElementsByClassName`.This will give a collection. Using `...` spread operator you can convert it to array and use `forEach` to loop over them and add an `change` event listener. and update the total on it's `change`.The value of the checkbox is string so using `parseInt` convert it to number

```js
let total = 0;
[...document.getElementsByClassName('iput')].forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      total += parseInt(e.target.value, 10)
    } else {
      total -= parseInt(e.target.value, 10)
    }
    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total
  })

})
```

```html
<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E33" value="4500" />
<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E34" value="3000" />
<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E36" value="6000" />

<p id="total">Your Total is = </p>
```

Comment: why someone will down vote all the answer?

Comment: I down voted some as they don't answer the question, some as they are w/o any explanation, and someone else obviously did too. If they still were good, I might have down voted them anyway, as when a user (OP) comes and ask for code to be written, and showing no effort of their own, that should not be encouraged, instead tell them to do what is expected before post, so we can have a decent standard on the questions asked (and posted answers).

Comment: @brk Thanks its working !

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only have inputs of type checkbox.

```
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var sum = 0;
checkboxes.forEach(function(checkbox){
  if (checkbox.checked) {
    sum += checkbox.value;
  }
});
console.log(sum); // your sum
```